# tar xf command giving file not found

Tags: tar, gzip

I am trying to extract one file out of the whole tar.gz and it's not working. Below are the commands i tried to simulate the issue

```
mkdir test
touch test/version.txt
echo "1.0.2" > test/version.txt 
tar zcvf rootfs.tar -C test .
gzip  -f -9 -n -c rootfs.tar > rootfs.tar.gz
tar xf rootfs.tar.gz version.txt

tar: version.txt: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Can you please provide the reason, there is version.txt file present in the above tar.gz

Comment: You compressed the archive twice. Once with tar's `z` option, once with gzip. Could this cause the problem?

Comment: Even if i remove the gzip command, i am still getting the error

Comment: You have to extract `./version.txt`, not `version.txt` (I see that Gilles has added this to his answer as well). By the way, to double-check the archive's content, just use `tar tf rootfs.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rootfs.tar` is a tar archive compressed with gzip. `rootfs.tar.gz` is a tar archive compressed with gzip twice. Tar seems to be confused by the double compression and treats the file as an empty archive instead of reporting an error.

Compressing twice is pointless, so remove this extra gzip step. To avoid confusion, call the compressed archive `rootfs.tar.gz` instead of `rootfs.tar`. And since the path you're passing to `tar` starts with `.`, you need to pass a path starting with `./` when extracting: tar does not treat `./` as a no-op in paths.

```
mkdir test
touch test/version.txt
echo "1.0.2" > test/version.txt 
tar zcvf rootfs.tar.gz -C test .
tar xf rootfs.tar.gz ./version.txt
```

If you want to avoid the `./` prefix in file names, you can use `--transform` when creating the archive.

```
tar zcvf rootfs.tar.gz --transform='s!^\./!!' -C test .
tar xf rootfs.tar.gz version.txt
```

Comment: I am still getting the error with above commands

Comment: @md.jamal You need to be consisted with the file name as well: either `./version.txt` both times or `version.txt` both times. See my edit.

Comment: Also, shouldn't that be "tar zxf" not "tar xf"? I don't think expecting tar to autodetect a compressed archive is portable.

Comment: @abligh At least GNU tar and FreeBSD tar recognize compressed archives automatically if the archive is in a regular file (not if it's read from a pipe or other non-seekable input). It's not the case with every tar implementation that recognizes the `z` flag, for example with BusyBox you need to pass it explicitly, but it is the case with the most prevalent implementations on a machine where you would typically build something called `rootfs`.

Comment: Please note that tere are tar implementations that automatically strip leading ./ from path names, wile creating an archive. Also note: `star` automatically detects compressed archives 25 years, Solaris tar does the same since 11 years and gtar/libarchive seem to do this since approx. the same time.